# Adding markers using OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers-2, openlayers, php

adding markers works fine using OpenLayers 2 but now I need to add markers using OpenLayers 4, how can I do this? my code as follows:

```
var markers = <?php echo json_encode($data)?>;

    var points = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers( "Markers" );


    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 

    var lon = markers[i][0];
    var lat = markers[i][1];

        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat)
        .transform(
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
        map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection

        );

    points.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat));

    };   

    map.addLayer(points);

    var poiBounds = points.getExtent();
    var lonLat = poiBounds.getCenterLonLat()
    map.setCenter (lonLat, 8)
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24316902/7280641), it shows how can use Marker (Feature in OpenLayers 4)

Answer (score 0):

```
// not var Markers   
var Markers = 
[
    {lat: 41.28247976112171, lng: 28.000645778308126},
    {lat: 41.28247976112171, lng: 28.000645778308126}
];

var myMap = new ol.Map({
    target: $element,
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([41.1878, 28.00158]),
        zoom: 6
    })
});

var features = [];


for (var i = 0; i < Markers.length; i++) {
    var item = Markers[i];
    var longitude = item.lng;
    var latitude = item.lat;

    var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([longitude, latitude], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
    });

    var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(({
            anchor: [0.5, 1],
            src: "http://cdn.mapmarker.io/api/v1/pin?text=P&size=50&hoffset=1"
        }))
    });

    iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
    features.push(iconFeature);

}

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: features
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});
myMap.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```